# Index Match multiple criteria with a `smaller than` criteria without arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data that is separated by `Date`, `Team` and their `Category Score`. `Category Score` changes for each `Team` on a daily basis and based on their actual score of the day, I'll need to identify the `Category Score` that they fall into.

For example, if on the 1st Jan 2018, Team A's score is 225. Team A's score whole fall in between 200 and 250. The assigned `Score Category` will then be rounded up to the last category which will be 200

However, the next day, Team A's `Score Category` is changed. The 225 score nicely rests on a `Score Category` and thus the assigned category will be 225.

Hopefully that gives a clear picture.

To help with the matter, the data is always sorted by `Date` and `Team` with ascending `Score Category`

I'm looking for an excel formula that hopefully does not use the array function.
I've so far looked at the Index Match formulas but they were all exact match that does not allow me to approximate to a value.

For e.g.

```
Date        Team    Score Category
1/1/2018    A       100
1/1/2018    A       150
1/1/2018    A       200
1/1/2018    A       250
1/1/2018    A       300
1/1/2018    B       300
1/1/2018    B       400
1/1/2018    B       500
2/1/2018    A       150
2/1/2018    A       200
2/1/2018    A       225
2/1/2018    A       300
2/1/2018    A       350
2/1/2018    B       350
2/1/2018    B       450
2/1/2018    B       550

Date:                       1/1/2018
Team:                       A
Actual Score:               225
Category Score (Output):    200


Date:                       2/1/2018
Team:                       A
Actual Score:               225
Category Score (Output):    225
```

Comment: Consider expending your Excl skills to use Macros VBA, That will give you (almost :) total control of your workbook

Comment: hmmm, I've actually thought about it. However considering that I would need to pass this document on to colleagues, it would be harder for them to understand/maintain the sheet if they don't understand VBA.

Comment: How is the `actual score` and `category score (output)` calculated? It's not clear to me what formula you need.

Comment: You can write a User Defined Function that does **exactely** what your after, than use it as you would any Excel fanction. Documant it to the croud - and there you are,

Comment: @AlexP `actual score` is one of the inputs that I have. It's recorded at the end of the end day when teams are done with their tasks. `category score (output)` would be (hopefully) the formula. I've tried using Index Match but can't seem to get an approximate match result.

Comment: If you or one of your team has basic programming scills [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel) will give you a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
= INDEX($C$2:$C$17,MATCH(B21,IF(($A$2:$A$17=B19)*($B$2:$B$17=B20),$C$2:$C$17),1))
```

Note this is an array formula, must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See below, working example with your data. I also copied this cell from `B22` to `B27`.

[image]

A few notes:

This formula only works if your `Score Categories` for a particular `Date` and `Team` combination are in ascending order (because using a third argument of `1` in `MATCH` requires that the data be sorted), but from the way your question is worded, it doesn't sound like this will be an issue.

The formula would probably also break if your `Score Categories` and/or `Actual Scores` are negative, since the `IF` statement effectively "zero's-out" the data you're not interested in for this particular `Date` and `Team` combination. But if the `Actual Score` is negative then it probably would erroneously consider one of these `0`'s as a match. This is just a guess, I didn't test this though.

Another thing to consider is to add a `Score Category` of `0` to the top of each `Date` and `Team` combination. I say this because if for example the `Actual Score` is lower than the lowest `Score Category` (e.g. if the `Actual Score` is `50` but the lowest `Score Category` is `100`), then a match won't be found, and I'm guessing the formula would return an error.